# Converting file encoding from ebcidic to Unicode

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding

I have a file in EBCDIC format and need to convert it to Unicode format as it contains some foreign language characters.

Comment: "Unicode" is not really a file format - the most common Unicode-based file format is UTF-8 (with or without BOM). Maybe this is helpful: https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/ebcdic/

Comment: I tried getting help from mentioned article.

When I change the original file encoding manually, characters like "‰" will be changed to "0X89" (note that I m using Notepad++ for opening these files and default format is ANSI and I manually select encoding UTF-8), but when i try to use the above mentioned program, it was "i".

I think I'm missing something. Please help.

Comment: You have to distinuish between the bytes (encoding) and the characters. Files consist of bytes; the encoding determines how these are interpreted as characters. In EBCDIC e.g. the byte 0x89 corresponds to the character "i". The same byte 0x89 is "‰" in Windows-1252.

Comment: I understand, but wont  some of the special characters in the original file change/lost when i first convert the file and then try to replace the bytes.
I'm wondering my approach should be first read the original file, replace the above bytes and then change the encoding. But this also contradicts as, when I open the file it will have symbols and not hexadecimals.
so what i understand here is i should try reading the file in hexa format first, replace the byte and then change encoding.
Would this be a correct approach?

Comment: Hi All, I have question following my main question. The output file I have should display both Chinese and English characters, but I m able to display only English ?What am I missing here?

Comment: Which encoding do you use? UTF8? How do you display the file?

Comment: I'm using UTF 8 to display the file and CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance.GetEncoding("CP500"); for reading the original file

Comment: Can you please provide a small reproducible example of this problem (not here in the comments but by editng your question).

Comment: Your edited question does not state what problem you have with the generated file. Can you provide some (short) input data, expected output and actual output?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is figure out what codepage is used to encode the EBCDIC file. The US EBCDIC codepage is 1137, but since you say there are foreign characters in the file, that's probably not what's used.

In this example I've used codepage 1142 which is the nordic EBCDIC codepage. I've put some EBCDIC characters in a byte array. Then I split the byte array into lines at every 0x09 byte and convert each line to a C# string. C# strings are unicode, so you should be able to write them to a new file without too much trouble.

I hope you can use this as a starting point.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] inputFile = new byte[] { 0x81, 0x82, 0x83, 0x09, 0xc0, 0x6a, 0xd0 }; 
        IEnumerable<byte[]> ebcdicLines = SplitBytes(inputFile);
        Encoding encoding = CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance.GetEncoding(1142); // Codepage 1142 is nordic EBCDIC
        IEnumerable<string> lines = ebcdicLines.Select(l => encoding.GetString(l)); // Convert each line to string (unicode)
        foreach (var line in lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<byte[]> SplitBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        int currentIndex = 0;
        int newlineIndex = Array.IndexOf(bytes, (byte)0x09, currentIndex);
        while (newlineIndex > -1)
        {
            yield return bytes.Skip(currentIndex).Take(newlineIndex - currentIndex).ToArray();
            currentIndex = newlineIndex + 1;
            newlineIndex = Array.IndexOf(bytes, (byte)0x09, currentIndex);
        }
        yield return bytes.Skip(currentIndex).ToArray();
    }
```